# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError on ruby 3.1.2

Tags: git, capistrano, sshkit

**Hi**

rails 7.0.3

ruby 3.1.2

both servers (production / staging) and the repository are on my own linux.

manually, i can ssh into production server and ssh from there to the repository server.

`git clone` from the production machine also does his work (manually, for testing).

i've done a `eval "${ssh-agent}"` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` on the production machine which runs fine but changes nothing

**The Problem**

`cap staging deploy --trace`

results in

```
[...]

00:01 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin repo-get@my-server.ch:/repos/pro-cnc/cncoffice.git
    ✔ 01 cncoffice@my-customer.com 0.098s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
    ✔ 02 cncoffice@my-customer.com 0.268s
** Execute git:create_release
00:01 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /srv/office/releases/20220701115330
    ✔ 01 cncoffice@my-customer.com 0.100s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /srv/office/releases/20220701115330
      02 fatal: Not a valid object name
      02 tar: This does not look like a tar archive
      02 tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
#<Thread:0x000000011398dc08 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as cncoffice@my-customer.com: git exit status: 2 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': git exit status: 2 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:83:in `git'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:73:in `archive_to_release_path'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:57:in `block (5 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:55:in `block (4 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:54:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
        from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as cncoffice@my-customer.com: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:83:in `git'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:73:in `archive_to_release_path'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:57:in `block (5 levels) in eval_rakefile'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:55:in `block (4 levels) in eval_rakefile'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capistrano-3.17.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:54:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as cncoffice@my-customer.com: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [ba3e6dbe] Command: if test ! -d /srv/office-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/srv/office-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [ba3e6dbe] Finished in 0.095 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [3174d347] Running /usr/bin/env git remote set-url origin repo-get@sedlmair.ch:/repos/pro-cnc/cncoffice.git as cncoffice@office.procnc.ch

 DEBUG [3174d347] Command: cd /srv/office-staging/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-7f405f262ce173c371af.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote set-url origin repo-get@sedlmair.ch:/repos/pro-cnc/cncoffice.git )

  INFO [3174d347] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [f60a0654] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune as cncoffice@office.procnc.ch

 DEBUG [f60a0654] Command: cd /srv/office-staging/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-7f405f262ce173c371af.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune )

 DEBUG [f60a0654]   Fetching origin

  INFO [f60a0654] Finished in 0.267 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [95047571] Running if test ! -d /srv/office-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/srv/office-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as cncoffice@office.procnc.ch

 DEBUG [95047571] Command: if test ! -d /srv/office-staging/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/srv/office-staging/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [95047571] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [bd721b6b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /srv/office-staging/releases/20220701123555 as cncoffice@office.procnc.ch

 DEBUG [bd721b6b] Command: cd /srv/office-staging/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-7f405f262ce173c371af.sh" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /srv/office-staging/releases/20220701123555 )

  INFO [bd721b6b] Finished in 0.106 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [31b8821b] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /srv/office-staging/releases/20220701123555 as cncoffice@office.procnc.ch

 DEBUG [31b8821b] Command: cd /srv/office-staging/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-7f405f262ce173c371af.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /srv/office-staging/releases/20220701123555 )

 DEBUG [31b8821b]   fatal: Not a valid object name

 DEBUG [31b8821b]   tar: This does not look like a tar archive

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

**Thanks,
Chris**

Comment: It looks like the deploy command is failing not necessarily related to ssh. Can you ssh into the machine and run the `staging deploy` task from within the remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your:

```
git archive master
```

command is producing:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name
```

This indicates that there's no branch named `master`.  That's likely because either:

- there are no branches at all (yet), or
- the main branch is named `main`, as most people do now instead of using `master`.

Check your Git repository to see whether you have any branch names at all (you don't *have to* have branch names, but practically nobody goes without them except in empty repositories) and if so, what they are.

Comment: Hi torek, exactly that was ist.